# Odd Output-Parameter value with ODAC 12.1

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, odac

I was reviewing an ASP.NET Visual Basic WebSite-Project last week and found the piece of code below which was behaving in a (to me) very strange way.

```
Using Connection As New OracleConnection(ConnMain)
Connection.Open()

Dim Command As OracleCommand = Connection.CreateCommand()
Dim Transaction As OracleTransaction
Dim Reader As OracleDataReader

Dim Sql As New StringBuilder

Transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction()
Command.Transaction = Transaction
Try
        Sql.Length = 0
        Sql.Append("  INSERT INTO DEMOTABLE (VALID,  ")
        Sql.Append("                          DB_NR,  ")
        Sql.Append("                          CREATED_DATE,  ")
        Sql.Append("                          CREATED_BY) ")
        Sql.Append("      VALUES ('Yes', ")
        Sql.Append("              :DB_NR_P,  ")
        Sql.Append("              SYSDATE,  ")
        Sql.Append("              :CREATED_BY_P)  ")
        Sql.Append("   RETURNING DEMOTABLE_ID  ")
        Sql.Append("        INTO :DEMOTABLE_ID_P ")

        Command.CommandText = Convert.ToString(Sql)
        Command.Parameters.Clear()

        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("DB_NR_P", ddlFirm.SelectedValue)
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("CREATED_BY_P", UserId)

        Dim DlcKombParam As OracleParameter = Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("DEMOTABLE_ID_P", "")
        DlcKombParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        DlcKombParam.Size = 255

        Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'handling the output-parameter
        Transaction.Commit()
Catch Ex As Exception
    Transaction.Rollback()
    WriteLog(Convert.ToString(Ex))
End Try
End Using
```

The confusion is with the Output-Parameter. The person who programmed this piece is using the same setup as me, the only difference being, he is using ODAC 11.2 and my machine already is on 12.1. (.Net 3.5, Oracle-DB 12.1, System.Data.OracleClient). On all machines with ODAC 11.2 (tested on three different ones) the parameter contains the ID of the newly inserted row. On my machine, the parameter contained only the first two digits of the five digit ID.
After changing the parameter (see below), the ID was returned correctly with both ODAC versions.

```
Dim DlcKombParam As New OracleParameter
DlcKombParam.ParameterName = "WEK_DLCKOMB_ID_P"
DlcKombParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
DlcKombParam.OracleType = OracleType.Number
```

My question is now: Why did the new ODAC-version return only the first two digits of the ID? I would've understand if it had returned an error (because the parameter in the original code was added as a string and this may have been classified as an error in the new version), or maybe even an empty string. 
But I can't wrap my head around why it would return only part of the value... Anyone got any ideas?